# ROS Kinetic Eigen

Tags: ros, eigen, ros-kinetic, eigen3, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since migrating from Indigo to Kinetic, i am receiving the following CMake warning:

> CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
> catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'eigen' but neither 'eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
> 'eigen_LIBRARIES' is defined.
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
> src_ros/iiwa_dynamics/CMakeLists.txt:110 (catkin_package)

Unfortunately I am unable to resolve this issue.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(iiwa_dynamics)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  ros_utilities
  tf_conversions
  iiwa_ik
)
find_package(cmake_modules REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system filesystem date_time thread)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES iiwa_dynamics
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
    roscpp
    std_msgs    
    geometry_msgs
    ros_utilities
    tf_conversions
    iiwa_ik
  DEPENDS
    eigen
)

include_directories(include)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
   src/iiwa_id.cpp
   src/iiwa_dynamics_core.cpp
 )

add_executable(iiwa_dynamics_debug src/iiwa_dynamics_debug.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(iiwa_dynamics_debug
   ${PROJECT_NAME}
 )


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
 add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

The corresponding package.xml:

```
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>ros_utilities</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf_conversions</build_depend>
  <build_depend>iiwa_ik</build_depend>
  <build_depend>eigen</build_depend>


  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>ros_utilities</run_depend>
  <run_depend>tf_conversions</run_depend>
  <run_depend>iiwa_ik</run_depend>
  <run_depend>eigen</run_depend>
```

Any suggestion on what is going wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253588/ros-kinetic-eigen/) by [Florian_W](https://answers.ros.org/users/24926/florian_w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin_package( .. DEPENDS ..)` basically makes it easier for ROS pkgs to export things like compile and linker flags by gathering all flags and then putting those in the right places for you.

For that it needs to know where those flags are stored (ie: the names of the variables), and that is what you tell it by giving it the `DEPENDS arg0 [arg1 ..[]]`list.

One assumption that is made -- to avoid having to manually list all the `arg0_LIBRARIES` and `arg1_INCLUDE_FLAGS` variables yourself, is that the `find_package()` scripts for your dependencies have properly *created and initialised those variables* and that *the name you provide (ie: `eigen` in your case) is actually the prefix used by the find-script in question*.

That last bit is a bit of a weakspot as there is no real requirement for find-scripts to do that, but it is something that Catkin assumes. But using those variable names is a recommended / best practice in CMake.

Looking at your `CMakeLists.txt`, I see `find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)`, but your `DEPENDS` argument has `eigen`. To know for sure we'd have to check what the find-script for `Eigen3` does, but it could well be that using `Eigen3` (or `eigen3`) in the `DEPENDS` list would resolve the issue you are experiencing.

---

Edit: from [this](https://github.com/ros/cmake_modules/issues/25#issuecomment-63561647) comment on [ros/cmake_modules#25](https://github.com/ros/cmake_modules/issues/25) I gather that the `Eigen3` find-script uses a `EIGEN3_` prefix.

Note btw that the Indigo->Jade migration guide has something to say about Eigen and Eigen3 as well: [Eigen CMake Module in cmake_modules](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Migration#Eigen_CMake_Module_in_cmake_modules).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Florian_W](https://answers.ros.org/users/24926/florian_w/) on 2017-02-02**:
using EIGEN3 in the DEPENDS resolved the porblem!